# heroku outputs "error fetching custom buildpack", but only sometimes

Tags: django, heroku, geodjango, buildpack

I have a Django project hosted on Heroku with a buildpack forked from [cirlabs/heroku-buildpack-geodjango](https://github.com/cirlabs/heroku-buildpack-geodjango). Sometimes when I push to Heroku it responds with

```
Counting objects: 16, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 790 bytes, done.
Total 9 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Fetching custom buildpack... failed
 !     Heroku push rejected, error fetching custom buildpack

To git@heroku.com:taplister-staging.git
 ! [remote rejected] dev -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:heroku-app.git'
```

I'm wondering if this may be an error with the buildpack itself, or if it's something about how Heroku interacts with github?

Oh, also among my `heroku config` is the buildpack URL

```
BUILDPACK_URL:              https://github.com/taplister/heroku-buildpack-geodjango
```

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This occasionally happens. Since you're using a custom buildpack, each time you push Heroku will download the buildpack over Git, and then use it to process your build.

Sometimes, depending on issues (network latency, temporary downtime, whatever) Heroku just won't be able to finish the Git clone, and will fail with the above error.

This is a known issue, and the only way around it is to retry the push.

Comment: for the record: this has been happening to me more and more... it eventually goes through though

Comment: same problem here.  Sometimes it takes many tries, unfortunatley

Comment: @Jiaaro et al. now it does not seem to work at all - for me.  Anyone else?

Comment: I've had the same problem for the last hour with https://github.com/jruby/heroku-buildpack-jruby.

Comment: I'm trying to push the heroku-buildpack-multi for the last hour with no success

Comment: You are not alone @nicolasiensen.

Comment: hey @Erik it probably was a connection issue, it's working now

Comment: Yep -- for me as well.  Nice to know when others are seeing the error though to confirm it is not a local issue.

Comment: I have same problem with dokku. Reboot of server saved my life!

Comment: I have this error now, and github seems down. Can't be a coincidence, the url is : https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs

Comment: Commenting in September 2023 with the same error. Any updates regarding this issue?!