# Heroku Push Rejected some references to some heroku app I don't have

Tags: heroku, deployment

I've got the following errors when I tried to push to staging on Heroku. I don't understand why.

```
$git push staging-heroku staging:master
Counting objects: 72, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (64/64), done.
Writing objects: 100% (72/72), 5.06 MiB | 837 KiB/s, done.
Total 72 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... failed

 !     Push rejected, error fetching custom buildpack

To git@heroku.com:pure-reef-7664.git
 ! [remote rejected] staging -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:pure-reef-7664.git'
[ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-78:~/bitstarter]$git push staging-heroku staging:master
Counting objects: 72, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (64/64), done.
Writing objects: 100% (72/72), 5.06 MiB | 766 KiB/s, done.
Total 72 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... failed

 !     Push rejected, error fetching custom buildpack

To git@heroku.com:pure-reef-7664.git
 ! [remote rejected] staging -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:pure-reef-7664.git'
```

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you've created your app with a "custom buildpack", either by invoking `heroku create myapp --buildpack http://...` or by setting the config var `BUILDPACK_URL`, and the URL you've provided is bad.

Make sure you have a valid URL and invoke `heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://<valid url>`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a custom buildpack and it's worked before, this is unfortunately something that "just happens" sometimes with Heroku (see the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11976734/221458)). Sometimes it goes through on the next push, other times I've had to wait up to a couple hours for it to work again. It's probably a good idea to open a support ticket with Heroku so they know something is borked.

If you aren't using a custom buildpack, have a look at Nitzan Shaked's answer.

**UPDATE**: In my case, where the buildpack was hosted on GitHub, Heroku Support advised to change the BUILDPACK_URL config var to use HTTPS instead of HTTP and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom buildpack with github, make sure that your repository is public.