# Heroku fails to build and push Clojure Project

Tags: git, heroku, clojure

I'm getting the following errors when I'm trying to do a `git push heroku master`

```
remote: Retrieving ring/ring-jetty-adapter/1.4.0/ring-jetty-adapter-1.4.0.jar from clojars
remote: Could not transfer artifact clj-http:clj-http:pom:2.1.0 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Error occurred while retrieving from  remote repository Repository[clojars|https://clojars.org/repo/]: Not in GZIP format
remote: Could not transfer artifact clj-json:clj-json:pom:0.5.3 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Error occurred while retrieving from remote repository Repository[clojars|https://clojars.org/repo/]: Not in GZIP format
remote: Could not transfer artifact clojure-csv:clojure-csv:pom:2.0.2 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Error occurred while retrieving from remote repository Repository[clojars|https://clojars.org/repo/]: Not in GZIP format
remote: Could not transfer artifact enlive:enlive:pom:1.1.6 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Error occurred while retrieving from remote repository Repository[clojars|https://clojars.org/repo/]: Not in GZIP format
remote: Could not transfer artifact hiccup:hiccup:pom:1.0.5 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Error occurred while retrieving from remote repository Repository[clojars|https://clojars.org/repo/]: Not in GZIP format
remote: Could not transfer artifact tinter:tinter:pom:0.1.1-20120609.171400-1 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Error occurred while retrieving from remote repository Repository[clojars|https://clojars.org/repo/]: Not in GZIP format
remote: Could not transfer artifact clj-time:clj-time:pom:0.11.0 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Error occurred while retrieving from remote repository Repository[clojars|https://clojars.org/repo/]: Not in GZIP format
remote: Could not transfer artifact jayq:jayq:pom:2.5.4 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Error occurred while retrieving from remote repository Repository[clojars|https://clojars.org/repo/]: Not in GZIP format
remote: Could not transfer artifact midje:midje:pom:1.8.3 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Error occurred while retrieving from remote repository Repository[clojars|https://clojars.org/repo/]: Not in GZIP format
remote: Could not transfer artifact ring-mock:ring-mock:pom:0.1.5 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Error occurred while retrieving from remote repository Repository[clojars|https://clojars.org/repo/]: Not in GZIP format
remote: Could not transfer artifact print-foo:print-foo:pom:1.0.2 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Error occurred while retrieving from remote repository Repository[clojars|https://clojars.org/repo/]: Not in GZIP format
remote: This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Clojure (Leiningen 2) app
```

My BUILDPACK_URL: https://github.com/kolov/heroku-buildpack-clojure

I've looked @ the following solution: [Heroku Push Rejected some references to some heroku app I don't have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347479/heroku-push-rejected-some-references-to-some-heroku-app-i-dont-have) but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using a forked buildpack, which is much older than the official Heroku buildpack (by 3 years). Your buildpack is also using a much older version of Leiningen.

I suggest switching to the default buildpack by running:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/clojure
```

Or by upgrading your custom buildpack to use a newer Lein version by changing [this line](https://github.com/kolov/heroku-buildpack-clojure/blob/master/bin/compile#L41) to:

```
LEIN_VERSION="2.6.1"
```

hope that helps